# what is difference between Gtk.Bin.Destroy() and Gtk.Bin.Dispose()

Tags: c#, gtk

I have a gtk bin control and I want to remove it. That means I need it to be removed from operating memory as well as from window. I am removing it from window by simply calling window.Remove(child_item), but should I call Destroy() or Dispose() or both as well? In which order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispose() is part of `GObject`, and it's used during the instance finalization sequence to release references and detach signal handlers; it can be called multiple times, in case of reference cycles, so it's a good practice to check for unset fields.

Destroy() is part of `GtkWidget`, and serves a similar purpose as the Dispose() implementation; Destroy() is pretty much an historical artefact of the fact that `GObject` started as an internal type of GTK before being moved out (alongside with the rest of the type system) into GLib. Destroy() is called as part of the default implementation of Dispose() inside `GtkWidget`.

if you want to remove a child from a container, you can simply call Remove(child) on the container, or Destroy() on the child: Remove() will release the reference held on the child, which will lead to the destruction of the widget, if that is the last reference. calling Destroy() on a `GtkWidget` will result on the widget being removed from its parent container. the two code paths should be interchangeable.

calling Dispose() directly is a Gtk#-ism: the Dispose() method is mostly intended to be overridden, not invoked directly.

Comment: Could you clarify the last paragraph, please? "Gtk#-ism" sounds like something that *should* by all means be done when using Gtk#, but the rest of the sentence implies it should *not* be done? Also, why should methods that get overridden not get invoked? And if, as you state above, `Dispose()` automatically calls `Destroy()` (not the other way round!), shouldn't it be `Dispose()` that needs to be called directly rather than `Destroy()`, if anything?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at GtkSharp 3.24.24.34 [source code](https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp/tree/3.24.24.34/Source/Libs/GtkSharp). I checked several widgets including `Bin` and its parents and the only place where the methods `Dispose()` and `Destroy()` are defined is the `Widget` class.

As you can see below, both methods are quite similar:

```
private bool destroyed;
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;

    if (disposing && !destroyed && IsToplevel)
    {
        //If this is a TopLevel widget, then we do not hold a ref, only a toggle ref.
        //Freeing our toggle ref expects a normal ref to exist, and therefore does not check if the object still exists.
        //Take a ref here and let our toggle ref unref it.
        g_object_ref (Handle);
        gtk_widget_destroy (Handle);
        destroyed = true;
    }

    InternalDestroyed -= NativeDestroyHandler;

    base.Dispose (disposing);
}

public virtual void Destroy ()
{
    if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        return;
    if (destroyed)
        return;
    gtk_widget_destroy (Handle);
    destroyed = true;

    InternalDestroyed -= NativeDestroyHandler;
}
```

The greatest difference I can see is that the `Dispose()` method calls `gtk_widget_destroy()` function only for top-level widgets and the top-level widgets are only `Window` and `Invisible` according to Gtk documentation. If I understand it correctly, `Dispose()` method is (almost) equal to `Destroy()` method only for top-level widgets such as `Window`.

From this finding I would prefer to call `Destroy()` method when I wanted to get rid of a single widget and left `Dispose()` method for the final cleanup on window close which is done by the garbage collector.